# Why can almost all ordinary mathematics be formalized by sets?

Tags: soft-question, foundations, philosophy

there must exists a reason of why the idea 'collection' is so powerful that it can formalize nearly all mathematics.

subquestion: is there any which can not be formalized by this perspective? if so, what properties make them informalizable?

Comment: A [realist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_realism#Mathematical_realism) will tell you that that's just the way it is, particularly set theory realists (like Gödel).

Comment: There is no such thing as *ordinary* mathematics.

Comment: @TooOldForMath The OP appears to be implicitly defining *ordinary* mathematics as *non-set theory* mathematics.

Comment: Of course there is such a thing as ordinary mathematics. It includes the core subjects such as analysis, algebra, geometry and topology. The exact boundaries are fuzzy, but that does not make the concept useless.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Almost all mathematics can be formalized without sets. For example, second-order arithmetic is good enough for most analysis and algebra. Particular theorems are usually provable in very weak formal systems, far weaker than set theory. (For instance, even though Andrew Wiles's proof of Fermat's theorem uses fancy set theory it is suspected that it can be transformed into a proof that only needs arithmetic, and we already know that only a bit of the set-theoretic universe is needed.)

When mathematics is *actually* formalized set theory is almost never used. Instead, people who formalize mathematics use proof assistants such as Agda, Coq, Isabelle, HOL, which are based on *type theory*. There are certainly similarities between sets and types, but types are more general than sets.

I have no doubts that it is *possible* to formalize mathematics in insanely unusual formal systems, as long as they are sufficiently expressive. So, to answer your question: mathematics can be formalized using sets because it can be formalized in any number of formal systems and there is nothing special about sets in this regard. It is just that humans invented sets and use them.

It's a bit like wondering why everyone drives cars that run on fossil fuels. Well, there are certainly many other ways to move around the planet, but this is the one we currently have, hopefully not for much longer.

We can further speculate why humans invented sets and types (which are similar to sets for the purposes of this discussion). This is not something that mathematics can answer by itself. We need to look at how people's minds work, how our language is structured, etc. I suspect we will discover that there is something very natural for us to think about "collections of things which are alike". Of course, the elements of a set need not be alike and can be quite arbitrary. So there are some surprising sets out there that we do not know how to cope with very well.

Comment: I think Gödel would disagree about there not being anything special about sets. *"But, despite their remoteness from sense experience, we do have something like a perception also of the objects of set theory, as is seen from the fact that the axioms force themselves upon us as being true"*, in *What is Cantor's Continuum Problem*.

Comment: I think without the idea 'collection' I can not even generate the concept 'two apples', or any further abstraction like number system.

Comment: @user126349, there is a long between between an intuitive notion of a "collection" and a ZFC notion of "set". This is what Andrej may have been trying to point out.

Comment: @user72694 There's a long way between speed/velocity and calculus as well. But it's an abstract way to represent them.

Comment: @Cruncher, this is precisely the point. There are different "abstract" formalisations of the same phenomena, and this includes calculus.  Thus, Leibniz mostly worked with differentials, whereas today we mostly work with derivatives.

Comment: There are several ways to mathematize the intuitive idea of collection, such as: set, type, space, (the extension of) a predicate, object of a category, etc. all of these may be taken as primitive. Naturally, they all resemble each other, but there really is nothing special about sets. I respect Gödel's opinion, and his position is understandable in historic context, but I disagree st sets are somehow inevitable or more primitive than other similar concepts.

Comment: It is a fact that actual formalizations of mathematics tend to use types rather than sets. This is extremely strong evidence in favor of the position that sets are not more primitive. Anyone arguing otherwise must explain this phenomenon.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer, is there anything special about the intuitive idea of collection? Actually this is the question I want to ask, not any formalization of this idea. I just feel it is in the nature and gave us a very clean view of things since Cantor.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, actual formalizations of mathematics tend to use sets as, or more often, than types from my observation. While many popular proof assistants can use type theory, it's incorrect to say that they are all based on type theory, rather they're based on logic that have several supporting foundations. Mizar and metamath are both ambitious attempts to formalize mathematics based on set theory, and many proof assistants are capable of using multiple independent theories.

Comment: Well, I can't argue against your personal experience. I am reporting on what the community around me is using. Mizar seems to be used by a fairly closed community, I know very little about Metamath. Also, in what sense are Mizar and Metamath proof *assistants*? They are proof *checkers*.